# Sql query to join 2 tables and count the values matching and non matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

I have two tables Employee and Department. I want to write a query that can give me data from both the tables with the count of the values.

```
    create table Employee(EmpID text);
    insert into Employee values("A");
    insert into Employee values("B");
    insert into Employee values("C");
```

```
    create table Departments(EmpID text);
    insert into Departments values("B");
    insert into Departments values("C");
    insert into Departments values("D");
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| EMP_ID    | COUNT     |
|--------   |-------    |
| A         | 1         |
| B         | 2         |
| C         | 2         |
| D         | 1         |
```

Searched everywhere, but didn't find anything helpful yet.
Here is the playground https://paiza.io/projects/TdkdHannoclhbevdqpFlKw?language=mysql

Below is the query I m trying out, using the full outer join as it gives all matching and unmatching rows

```
SELECT *FROM Employee outer join Departments on Employee.EmpID=Departments.EmpID
```

Comment: UNION ALL, GROUP BY the result.

Comment: Hey @jarlh, I tried that too, but not working. I have added the playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a strange data model.  But use `union all` and then `group by`:

```
select empid, count(*)
from (select empid from employee union all
      select empid from department
     ) e
group by empid;
```

That you have `empid` in `department` that does not match `empid`s in `employee` is a *data modeling problem*.  You should have a foreign key relationship from `department` to `employee` to ensure that this can never happens.  Your database lacks relational integrity.

Comment: This is just a scenario, sum1 asked me and I was trying out. I was trying to use outer join, but it didn't worked out

Comment: Is there a way to do it using outer join?

Comment: @HeenaTabassum . . . Not in MySQL.  That would require an `full join`.  This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select empid, count(empid)
from (
      select empid from employee 
      union all
      select empid from department
     ) e
group by empid;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [Tips for Quality Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL

see: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

or you can look into (temporary) merged tables

see: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html)